# Forcing ARC to work

Tags: ios, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I'm writing an app, that does a lot of heavy image processing.

I have a very big loop, with the average execution time more than a minute. Sometimes (with big images) I get memory warnings and he app crashes. I'm sure that there are no leaks, because consumed memory gets released fine, when the loop ends.

I'm using `myImage = nil` for all images on evey iteration, but it does not make any difference.

I think the root of this issue is the fact, that ARC is freeing memory only, when system is idle — between my function calls. Am I right? Is there a way to force ARC to clean-up unused memory immediately, without waiting for my method to end?

Comment: Have you run the static analyser on you project? I would put money on the fact that it is not ARC causing this. They have a team of people that have been working on it for a considerable amount of time. Compared to you writing your one image processing loop. Also, can you show the code in the loop? Run the static analyser first though.

Comment: Title is misleading - you can't force arc to work.

Comment: Run leaks and general memory analysis on your project. If things are still weird, create an autorelease pool inside your loop.

Comment: ARC is not freeing memory only when your system is idle. ARC is not a garbage collector! Mostly it will free memory immediately.

Comment: Sorry, if title is misleading — English is not my native language, so my explanation may be far from perfect.

Comment: @Fogmeister, @Sulthan, ARC works exactly as wrote in my question: it deallocates memory only at the moment, when you return from your function, unless you wrap your code in autoreleasepool block. 
Try yourself, this code will consume all available memory and crash you app:
`for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++) { UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bigPhoto.jpg"]; }`
            
But this code will not consume a single extra byte:
`for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++) @autoreleasepool { UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bigPhoto.jpg"]; }`

Comment: @Stanislav I never said otherwise. However, you didn't say that, you said "ARC is freeing memory only, when system is idle". That is what Garbage Collection is. ARC is a COMPILE time system that puts back in to your program the release calls that you no longer have to write yourself. However, my first comment still stands. And did you run the Static Analyser yet?

Comment: @Fogmeister, in russian language phrases "idle system" and "executing outside of my functions" are pretty similar. My problem is already solved, by using `@autoreleasepool` block — it worked perfectly to force ARC dealloc memory immideatly, without waiting for function to return. Now my app's memory level is constant during all the proccessing.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Not sure why you started complaining to me though. LOL! Also, did you run the static analyser before you added the auto release pool?

Comment: Yes, running it was my first action: no issues. After that I tried Memory Leak Instrument. After that I spent couple of hours researching and simplfying an app. And only after that I posted a question to stackoverflow.

I'm sorry if it looks like I'm complaining: it only looks this way, because smiley's are not welcome on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an @autoreleasepool inside your loop, like so:

```
for (loop stuff) {
    @autoreleasepool {
         // code code code 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple word **It's not possible** to force ARC to call the autorelease pool, most time memory problem with ARC comes with retain cycle so you always make sure that you do not write kinda code that lead retain cycle!

Comment: It's actually very easy to make ARC drain the pool. That's why there are `@autoreleasepool` blocks.

Comment: Autorelease pool blocks provide a mechanism whereby you can relinquish ownership of an object, but it can not be forced to drain memory as I know, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You are wrong. `@autoreleasepool { ... }` have one and only one purpose. To release everything that has been autoreleased in their scope.

Comment: Sulthan, thank you. Little reading about autoreleasepools solved my problem. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.